# Convert .mp4 to .mp3 using pure PHP

Tags: php, mp3, mp4

How do I convert a video (.mp4) from an external site (ex: youtube.com) to an .mp3 using PHP without wasting a lot of resources? So similar to http://youtube-mp3.org/, they are able to convert it very easily.

Thanks.

Comment: "Very easily" maybe, but you don't know how many resources they "waste".

Answer (score 4):

you can convert it by shell-command  eg [*]

```
  <?php 
      exec('ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3');
  ?>
```

- if your OS is unix and ffmpeg is installed

Comment: Will it work with a remote file? For example http://video.com/video.mp4? `exec('ffmpeg -i http://video.com/video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3');`

Comment: And it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I don't think ffmpeg is installed. I use shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Pure PHP is not suitable for this task.

Let the user upload the file via PHP. Then direct PHP (via the exec() function) an external program like ***ffmpeg*** or ***gstreamer*** to convert the file. After the conversion you can make the mp3 available for downloading via PHP.

This is in my opinion the only suitable approach to this kind of problem, because programs like ffmpeg use much less resources than a PHP Script would need.

Comment: I don't have `ffmpeg` nor `gstreamer` installed on my shared hosting.