# Can I convert mp3 files to mp4 on the fly in a browser?

Tags: audio, video, browser, type-conversion, playstation

The playstation 4's browser cannot play any audio files via html5, but it can play .mp4 files. I have a server with all my music on it (all .mp3 or .m4a) and I was wondering if there was any way to, in the playstation 4 browser, convert files to .mp4. If the files could be converted as the page loads, I can point  tags to the newly converted .mp4 files. Even if there's some button I have to press to convert one file at a time, it's still better than nothing. Other solutions are welcome too.

Thanks, all

Comment: Your question was clear until I reached the last sentence... of course there are many utilities that can convert audio files from one format to another, varying from user friendly graphical programs to down-to-business, just-get-the-job-done command line utilities. Easy to find on the web.

Comment: @MrLister I'm aware of the file conversion programs out there, but I was talking about anything that could convert server side. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: That depends wholly on what kind of server you have and what's installed on it. See, for instance, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895207/convert-mp4-to-mp3-using-pure-php

Comment: @MrLister I have absolutely no experience with server programs. I was hoping for a javascript solution, which seems less complicated than PHP. If there is a way to convert from one server and save to another server, that might work. I can make as many servers as I need. I'm just too ignorant of this server stuff to think of anything. Any solutions would have to be compatible with the playstation 4 browser to be helpful.